# App not being loaded in the emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/nutritionfactsorg/daily-dozen-android) project in the emulator through Android Studio (4.1.1) on Ubuntu 18.04. Everything seems to be set up properly in Android Studio, I have a device called `Pixel XL API 29` and the emulator starts up but it doesn't open the app and I can't find the app in all apps.

At first, I had a couple of issues with the emulator not starting up at all but I managed to fix those - something to do with kvm - had to change some user settings and then restart my laptop.

I've tried googling but no solution yet, mostly I find issues with installing apps from the Google Play Store.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Did you install the app in emulator using `adb install`? What message it shows? Did you check apps list in Settings?

Comment: If you don't want to make changes to the app I would recommend to you to just download the APK file from FDroid (there is a direct APK download link for each version of the FDroid app's page) and the install it using `adb install`.

Comment: @Robert I need to make changes to the app. Irfan, I found it in the Settings app lists of apps, even managed to run it from there. Any idea why it won't run by default and I can't see it in the app list?

Comment: Works for me without problems after I added a fake `google-services.json` to the project. Runs in emulator and app is directly opened.

Comment: Very strange. I'll try it on my other computer.

Comment: @PetarVasilev you can use a different home/launcher app. There are abundant.

Comment: @IrfanLatif what do you mean by that?

Comment: Aaaa you mean an app that handles the UI of the home screen and all apps sections?

Comment: @PetarVasilev yes.